# How do I get an app to change information at a certain time?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift so my question might sound elementary.
I was hoping to have a system that changes the information in an app when it e.g was the next day.

I tried to find an answer but didn't know exactly what to search so I emerged empty handed.

I was thinking even having a label of text or a button change the next day like a word of the day style mechanism.

Anyone have any ideas as to how I'd go by that?

Answer (score 3):

You can detect time changes in your `AppDelegate.swift` file by implementing the `applicationSignificantTimeChange` method. This will be called every now and then, for example when it's a new day.

```
func applicationSignificantTimeChange(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let dayOfYear = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: Date())
    print(dayOfYear)
}
```

> Examples of significant time changes include the arrival of midnight, an update of the time by a carrier, and the change to daylight savings time. The delegate can implement this method to adjust any object of the app that displays time or is sensitive to time changes.